# How do I play this UMD format movie?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, vlc-media-player, mpv

I have a movie ripped from a [UMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Media_Disc) format disc in the form of an ISO.

The ISO structure is as follows:

```
$ls -R
.:
umd_data.bin  umd_video

./umd_video:
clipinf  icon0.png  icon1.pmf  param.sfo  pic1.png  playlist.umd  resource  snd0.at3  stream

./umd_video/clipinf:
00001.clp  00002.clp  00003.clp  00004.clp  00005.clp  00006.clp

./umd_video/resource:
en000001.rco  en100000.rco

./umd_video/stream:
00001.mps  00002.mps  00003.mps  00004.mps  00005.mps  00006.mps
```

I am unable to open the whole disc using [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/) or [MPV](https://mpv.io/). When I went through all the files, I found that `00001.mps` is the actual movie, and I tried to open the file with both VLC and MPV.

With VLC, I see a timeline and I can scrub the video, but there's no audio or video output. In the codec information tab, I see one video stream(mpgv codec), three subtitle streams(cvd codec), and three audio streams(a52 codec). In MPV, I see a video output but no audio. I see five audio streams, no subtitles, and one video stream. When I open the file in the Haruna frontend for MPV, I see five Audio output streams all labelled ac3. I tried selecting all of them, but there's still no audio playback. When I open the file with VLC, sometimes the audio streams in the Codec information just disappear, which makes me suspect that the file might be corrupted or in a format not easily readable by these media players. When I ran the mediainfo command (from [here](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo)), I get the following output

```
$mediainfo 00001.mps
General
Complete name                            : 00001.mps
Format                                   : MPEG-PS
File size                                : 1.59 GiB
Duration                                 : 1 h 59 min
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 1 893 kb/s
FileExtension_Invalid                    : mpeg mpg m2p vob vro pss evo

Video
ID                                       : 224 (0xE0)
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L3
Format settings                          : CABAC / 2 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 2 frames
Duration                                 : 1 h 59 min
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 1 856 kb/s
Maximum bit rate                         : 8 000 kb/s
Width                                    : 720 pixels
Height                                   : 480 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate                               : 29.970 (30000/1001) FPS
Standard                                 : NTSC
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Interlaced
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.179
Stream size                              : 1.56 GiB (98%)
Color range                              : Full

Text #1
ID                                       : 189 (0xBD)
Format                                   : RLE
Format/Info                              : Run-length encoding
Duration                                 : 1 h 59 min
Delay relative to video                  : -50 ms

Text #2
ID                                       : 189 (0xBD)-1 (0x1)
Format                                   : RLE
Format/Info                              : Run-length encoding
Muxing mode                              : DVD-Video
Duration                                 : 1 h 59 min
Delay relative to video                  : -50 ms

Text #3
ID                                       : 189 (0xBD)-2 (0x2)
Format                                   : RLE
Format/Info                              : Run-length encoding
Muxing mode                              : DVD-Video
Duration                                 : 1 h 59 min
Delay relative to video                  : -50 ms

Menu
```

Is this file valid or most likely corrupted? If it's valid, how do I go about playing it? I have a `.srt` file, so I could just watch the movie with subtitles on mpv, but I would still prefer having some audio, if it actually exists.

Thank you all in advance for your help, and I wish you all a nice day.

Comment: Have you succeeded in playing anything using UMD on VLC or MPV ?

Comment: @RohitGupta No. However, I was able to get the video output from the .mps file using MPV as discussed earlier.

Comment: I'd honestly weight up the effort in persuading this to work - & the fact it's only 720i if you do - against just sourcing the movie elsewhere, ready to go. It would have to be rare/special to be worth the effort really ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin I could get it from another source, but I wanted to try this out of pure academic curiosity and to improve my knowledge of media debugging for any future situations.

Comment: Fair  enough. ;)

Comment: Which movie is it?

Comment: UMD apparently uses [DVD Region Coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Media_Disc#Region_coding) for protection. You may have to see if you can remove the copy protection: https://www.google.com/search?q=remove+dvd+copy+protection+files

Comment: @Gantendo Crouching Tiger Hidden Dragon. I will check to see how the region coding can be removed.

Comment: @Mokubai The audio and subtitle tracks weren't recognized in Handbrake. However, I was able to play the video on a PSP emulator (JPCSP) and the audio tracks do indeed exist.